# Textmessage containing an appstore link

Tags: iphone, url, schema, itunes

how do I build a link, which opens the appstore and shows an app (something like itms://myapplication?action=show). I want to send that link via a text message (over the web). All I've found was the ITMS link generator.

Best regards,

Stefan

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with the ITMS link generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the link to an application, use the iTunes Link Maker, as you found, or: open iTunes, right-click on the desired app, and choose Copy Link.

[copying iTunes link http://grab.by/Eqq](http://grab.by/Eqq)

This link will open the App Store when it's accessed on an iPhone. I don't know how you're sending this via text message, but you can just include that URL. To open it in code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
 [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/blah"]];
```

Comment: Note that a URL shortener like http://bit.ly/ would be a good idea, as text messages are limited in characters.